# How to loop indices of .formula/.formulaR1C1

Tags: excel, for-loop, excel-formula, vba

I am stuck with a problem i cannot get my head around currently.

I have a checklist that has to update automatically when adding lines to my excel worksheet so that the checklist is applied to all rows.
I tried to use a "for loop" to modify the formula but excel returns Error 1004, when starting the string with "=".

No error but no functionality as well:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkulation Änderungen").Range("AB9").FormulaLocal = "Wenn(Oder(AB" & firstRow & "=""x"""
```

Returns error 1004:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkulation Änderungen").Range("AB9").FormulaLocal = "=Wenn(Oder(AB" & firstRow & "=""x"""
```

**My first solution** 
Loop FormulaR1C1, or Formula and use nothing but english Function names eg. sum() instead of Summe() and follow english syntax , instead of ;.

**Problem**
When testing the syntax without a loop and actual indices it works like a charm. As soon as I try to loop it, Excel does not recognize R[i]C as cell anymore but just returns plain text.

no issues:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkulation Änderungen").Range("AB9").Formula = "IF(OR( R[1]C = ""x"""
```

issues:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkulation Änderungen").Range("AB9").Formula = "IF(OR( R[i]C = ""x"""
```

Splitting it like this did not solve my problem either
    ..R[" & i & "]C =..

Any tips?

// For i=  ... to .. next i
// Excel 2007

Comment: What is the expected value of `IF(OR( R[1]C = ""x""`? i get an error with no return value, despite its only working with the german formula. Like: `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A9").FormulaLocal = "=WENN(z" & i & "s =""x"";""True"";""False"")"`

Comment: Well, the aim is to have a list of different tasks (to do list) represented by rows and the "departments" or components affected by those work steps.
The first row of my table is my header that checks the cells below and if at least one is ticked with an "x", returns an "x" as well.
Formula for column one header (shortened):
 =WENN(ODER(AE10 ="x";AE11="x";AE12="x");"x";" ") 

But as soon as I include "=" in my string it returns error 1004.

Comment: Seems to be some sort of compiling or syntax error in Excel 2007. When setting the formula manually and not automatically with vba, I get no issues.

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A9").FormulaLocal = "=WENN(z" & i & "s =""x"";""True"";""False"")"                                       .

Why ["s=""x""]?
thanks for your help

Comment: Its very strange tbh. i took your formula changed ´AE` to `A` and it didnt work, then i entered it with hand it just worked. For a Range you have to use `A10:E10` or it will no recognize the fields, you can see that when entering the formula it will highlight the cells

Comment: Thats r1c1 or in german z1s1 notation. so it would be for `i=10` `z10s ="x"`.

Comment: i think it would be much easier if you just use a function to watch the worksheet and then fill in the x and go around using any kind of in cell formula.

Comment: I have been thinking that my approach to the problem is a little of and too complicated. 
I actually just wanted Excel to check all the rows of one column  (range AB10:AB20 eg:) and check if at least one equals "x". But no matter how i tried, it just returned an error when comparing the range with a string.
That is the reason why i tried to loop it  and modify the header in vba, which works with the germannotation unless i include "=".

The english notation does not interpret "i" as a counter for some reason. As an excel beginner i am a bit lost...
Thanks for your help tho ;). Appreciated

Comment: So i have a button that just updates the grid on click thus does not work in realtime?

Comment: `AB10:AB20` is not a right range assignment. Its `A10:A20` for Column A or `A10:B20` for Column A and B. I will make up a short code to show you, how you can do it.

Comment: Well when you go further than Z Excel starts naming the columns AA AB AC...BA etc.
Some code would be nice (Y)

Comment: Im sorry for that, didnt work so far to the right normally. i posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkulation Änderungen")
      'find last row of column AB
      LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
      'apply the formula from AB9 to its last non-blank row
     .Range("AB9:AB" & LastRow).Formula = "IF(OR( R[1]C = ""x"""
   End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I guess i can make use of your RowcountLine in one of my other projects. Seems useful and efficent.
The reason for my "for loop" ist that although lines get added, just the "header" ( the topmost line) has a set formula and has to be modified when adding lines.
My idea was  to: 1. count the rows 2.use a loop to modify the Header's formula. (eg. 20 lines --> 20 loops --> R[1]C ="x" to R[20]C ="x" (20 entries in my if(or(....,"x"," ") formula.)
That is why i asked specifically for the Problems with icounters in FormulaR1C1 and Error 1004 in .formulalocal when using "="

Comment: Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code. It has to be in the corresponding worksheet in the VBA-Editor. 
It activates when a cell in `Range(A10:A20)` has been changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = Range("A10:A20")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Count = 1 Then
            If Target.Value = "x" Then
                'Your Code
                'i.e
                MsgBox (Target.Address & "has been changed")
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox ("Please No Copy Pasterino")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim fRow As Long, lRow As Long
Dim check As Boolean
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Tabelle1")

'Rowcount
fRow = 2
lRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

' check column AB fo "x" and modify header
Set KeyCells = Range("AB" & fRow & ":AI" & lRow)
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then
         For Each Cell In Range(Cells(fRow, Target.Column), Cells(lRow, Target.Column))
            If Cell.Value = "x" Then
                sht.Cells(9, Target.Column).Value = "x"
                Exit For
            Else
                sht.Cells(9, Target.Column).Value = ""
            End If
         Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks awesome, I will check if it works for me later on. 
Great support (Y) 
Have you learned excel through practical application or did you take courses?

Comment: I posted an answer with my current thought, in case you are interested ;).
The intersect part is some smart piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

@UGP: that is what i thought the code might look like after implementing your tips with intersect etc.
What do you think of it, I guess you might not like the loops too much?
Typical beginner approach to loop everything?

I would have to do this for every column accordingly?
If so it would be wise to create a sub () for every column with an exit condition so that i save computing time?

Unless it is possible to hand over the columnadress to the sub_worksheet_change()?

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range, selected_column)

_
_

_
_

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim KeyCells As Range
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim check As Boolean

   frstRow = 1
   lastRow = 1
   i = 1


'Rowcount 
    Do Until firstRow <> 1 And lastRow <> 1

          If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkulation Änderungen").Range("D" & i) = "Länge" Then
             firstRow = i + 2
             i = i + 1
          End If
          If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkulation Änderungen").Range("G" & i) = "Gesamt-h" Then
             lastRow = i - 2
         End If

    i = i + 1
    Loop

   ' check column AB fo "x" and modify header
   Set KeyCells = Range("AB" & firstRow, "AI" & lastRow)
   check = False
   i = firstRow
   If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
          Is Nothing Then
            Do While i <= lastRow And check = False
               If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkulation Änderungen").Range("AB" & i).Value = "x" Then
                  check = True
                  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkulation Änderungen").Range("AB9").Value = "x"
               ElseIf i = lastRow And check = False Then
                  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Kalkulation Änderungen").Range("AB9").Value = " "
               End If
            i = i + 1
            Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can do that in this sub. i dont understand your first loop for the rowcount. where does the data start and end. Could you attach a screenshot of your table?

Comment: It is a calculation sheet, so i have quite a few tables on it. I linked the exit condition to a string above and below the table.That will not change its position since it is part of the table, It returns the right line.  
I not allowed to share that data :/, sorry.

Would you make a array of KeyCells so that i can implement every column by hand or rather a case? The column are  independent to each other.

Comment: You dont have to share the data, i would be cool if you could make a seperate file with junk data and just the the thing you need for this code. i only need to see the raw structure not the data itself. What do you mean by multiple colums? Do you want to do the same thing just with a different column and edit the header to that corresponding col?

Comment: Exactly how you described it! I am not sure what might be more applicable, a case, seperate subs ().

Ok. I can do this i think, next time i have some spare minutes ill upload it.

Comment: i added a version to my answer, you can check if i got the idea you had. it probably looks more confusion than its actually is. What i concluded from you answer is that: last data set in Col `G` marks lastRow, firstRow starts somewhere in Col `H`, but i couldnt figure out where as i already said. so if you have data in Col `G` and the lastRow is 5, if you then edit a cell in `Range("AB:AI")` with a `x` it will  check l- fRow in the column you made an edit and put nothing or ´x` in Row 9 of the corresponding cell. If you post a screenshot with structure, i can help you with the rest.